# Rest,Jersey,Spring,IOC-AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext No beans found

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, inversion-of-control

I am trying to inject a bean into a Rest Resource implemented using Jersey.

I am using Spring to Inject the bean.

The application loads on tamcat without Spring complaining for any bean loading issues.

But When I run the application,Jersey itself gives the following exception.

I am using jersey version of 2.4.1.

Here is my Warning :

```
WARNING [http-nio-9090-exec-73] org.glassfish.jersey.se
rver.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext No beans found. Res
olution failed for type interface net.fxdms.dmb.abc.application.exInterface.
```

I have tried different combinations of `@Autowired/@Inject with @Service/@Component.`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem with jersey 2.6 and Spring 3.1
Here is sources of AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext

```
 private Object getBeanFromSpringContext(String beanName, Type beanType) {
        Class<?> bt = getClassFromType(beanType);
        if(beanName != null) {
            return ctx.getBean(beanName, bt);
        }
        Map<String, ?> beans = ctx.getBeansOfType(bt);
        if(beans == null || beans.size() != 1) {
            LOGGER.warning(LocalizationMessages.NO_BEANS_FOUND_FOR_TYPE(beanType));
            return null;
        }
        return beans.values().iterator().next();
    }
```

In my case there was two beans of requested for @Autowire type. Firstis actually my bean, second - scopetTarged of my bean.

My bean definition was like

```
<bean id="apiUserService" class="uk.co.itrainconsulting.appbook.core.impl.service.APIUserServiceImpl">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
    <property name="entityDAO" ref="apiUserManager" />
</bean>
```

I solved the problem by removing aop:scoped-proxy from bean definition